# How can I apply a filter using Softlayer's ticket API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ticket-system

I tried to receive a full list of tickets with the following code snipped:

```
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username="xxx", api_key="xxx")
client['Account'].getTickets(mask='id')
```

Even so I mask the output to only return `'id'` it fails in one of my Softlayer accounts with `SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error`. I have over 1.4 millions tickets (including closed) in that account.

Next I tried to apply a filter:

```
tickets = client.call('Account', 'getTickets',
                      filter={'id': { 'operation': 48076123 }}
# or
tickets = client.call('Account', 'getTickets',
                      filter={'id': { 'operation': '>48076123' }}
```

But it always returns the complete list of tickets and fails the same way on the accounts with a high number of tickets. I need to create a history of all tickets.

Is there are way to limit the query or create a window over the results?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your objectMask should be

> client['Account'].getTickets(mask="mask[id]")

your fitler should be:

> tickets = client.call('Account', 'getTickets',
>                         filter={"tickets":{"id":{"operation":48076123}}}

and also you can limmit the result using the pagination

```
client.call('Account', 'getTickets', limit=10, offset=0)
```

see https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/docs/api/client.rst for more information

Comment: I think the pagination is the solution I was looking for. Thank you.